# google calendar api delphi

Tags: delphi, google-calendar-api

I have been programming in DELPHI, work with google calendar and I want to delete an event but I have to go bug.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click (Sender: TObject);    
var    
 url: string;    
 slParam: TStringList;    
begin    
  test: ='';    
  IdHTTP2.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;    
  IdHTTP2.Request.Connection: = 'Keep-Alive';    
  IdHTTP2.Request.ContentType: = 'application / atom xml';    
  IdHTTP2.Request.CustomHeaders.Values ['GData-Version']: = '2';    
  IdHTTP2.Request.CustomHeaders.Values ['Authorization']: = 'GoogleLogin auth =' auth;    
  IdHTTP2.HandleRedirects: = true;    
  url: =  http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/u0qtqn2cke6pjppu1vgj5pj8js  %40group.calendar.google.com/private/full    
  slParam: = TStringList.Create;    
  slParam.LoadFromFile ('udalit.xml');    
  try    
    test: = IdHTTP2.Post (url, slParam);    
    memo1.Lines.Add (test);    
  except    
 on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do    
   ShowMessage (E.ErrorMessage);    
  end;    
  FreeAndNil (slParam);    
end;
```

Here is my xml file I'm trying to send

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>   
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch" xmlns:gCal="http://schemas.google.com/gCal/2005" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">  
<category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event" />   
<entry gd:etag=""FEUDQAdBfSp7JGA6WhJV"">  
<batch:id>Delete itemD</batch:id>   
<batch:operation type="delete" />   
<id>http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/u0qtqn2cke6pjppu1vgj5pj8js%40group.calendar.google.com/private/full/ihpe431ebmk9pa39dskjilnsko</id>   
</entry>  
</feed>
```

will generate an error when sending

> [Line 1, Column 227] Invalid root element, expected
>   (http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom:entry), got
>   (http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom:feed)

Comment: The HTTP specification forbids spaces like you have in your Content-Type header. You should also try to spell it correctly: `application/atom+xml` has a plus sign that's required. You also have syntax errors throughout your code. Please copy and paste real code, or else people won't trust that the problem you're reporting is real.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you don't need to send a file to delete an event. According to the [Calendar API](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/calendar_resource/docs/1.0/calendar_resource_developers_guide_protocol.html#Deleting_calendar), you just need to call the URI.

> To delete a calendar resource, send a DELETE request to a resource ID's feed URL. Include the Authorization header as described in Authenticating.
>
> DELETE https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/calendar/resource/2.0/{domain name}/{resourceId}
>
> A successful response returns an HTTP 200 status code from the Google Data API status codes. The XML body of a successful response to a DELETE request is empty.