# Delete event in google calendar with Delphi

Tags: delphi, google-calendar-api, idhttp

I need to delete an event, what I do is save the ID of the event in a database and then use that url thttpid.delete to remove it, but I get an error 402 forbidden

```
Code= 'XXXXxxXXXxx' // ClientLogin code
URL:='https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/XXXX%40gmail.com/private/full/XXXXo8aqjok24794auifouXXXX' // ID GOOGLE EVENT 


    function TForm4.DeleteGoogle(Code,URL:String): String;
    begin
          idHTTP2.IOHandler:=IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
          idHTTP2.Request.Connection  := 'Keep-Alive';
          idHTTP2.Request.ContentType := 'application/atom+xml';
          idHTTP2.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['GData-Version']:='2.0';
          idHTTP2.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization']:=('GoogleLogin Auth='+Code);
          try
            idHTTP2.Delete(URL);
          except on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
            idHTTP2.Delete(URL);
          end;
          //ID
             Result:=(IdHTTP2.Response.Location);
    end;
```

What is the url I need to delete this event?.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete an entry from an RSS Feed.  A Feed is read-only, meant for exchanging data across systems.  You need to use Google's Calendar API to login to the actual calendar and then delete the desired entry from there.

[Google Calendar API v1](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v1/developers_guide_protocol):

[Deleting Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v1/developers_guide_protocol#DeletingEvents)

[Google Calendar API v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/):

[Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/#Events)

[Events: delete](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete)

Comment: Are you sure? According to [google calendar api delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9308260), you can. Has it changed since then? (Not arguing - just asking.)

Comment: I needed to add tidhttp the header 'if-match' and add the tag value, fixed

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the header 'if-match' and add the tag value. Doing so fixed the problem.

```
IdHTTP2.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['If-Match']:=tag;
```